Is there an example of a TVS on which there is no nonzero continuous linear functional.
Let $f: X \rightarrow K$ be a nonzero continuous linear functional on a topological vector space (TVS).
Prove that the set $U = \{x \in X: f(x) < 1\}$ is an open convex set in $X$ containing 0.
Bonus: Give an example of a TVS on which there is no nonzero continuous linear functional. (Hint: It should contain no open convex neighborhood of 0. Try $\mathbb{K}^2$ with the topology defined by the metric
$$d((x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2)) = (\sqrt{|x_1 - y_1|} + \sqrt{|x_2 - y_2|})^2.$$)
I have proved the first question, but i dont know how to give a example according to the hint, the question want me to give the example by using the property I just proved, maybe some contradiction exsit.

For the question in the title, $\ell^{p}$ with $0<p<1$ is a well known example.

for example $$d((0, 1), (1, 0)) = 4 > d((0,1), (0,0)) + d((0,0), (1,0)) =2$$
so this doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality.

$L^0(0, 1)$ with the topology of convergence in measure is another well-known example for the question in the title.

As mentioned in the comments, the $L^p$ spaces for $0<p<1$ are some basic examples of an infinite dimensional TVS that has a trivial dual space.
Consider $L^p(0,1), 0<p<1,$ endowed by the translation invariant metric $d(f,g) = \int_0^1 |f-g|^p$. This is a TVS whose dual $(L^p(0,1))^*=\{0\}$. Indeed,  suppose that  $x^* \colon L^p(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is a bounded linear functional. The idea is to construct  a sequence $(f_n)$ in $L_p(0,1)$ such that $|x^* (f_n)  | \ge 1$ and $d(f_n,0) \to  0$, contradicting the continuity of $x^*$.
Fix $f \in L_p(0,1)$ such that $|\phi(f)| \ge 1$. The indefinite integral $x \mapsto \int_0^x |f(s)|^p ds$ is continuous and so there exists $x \in (0,1)$ such that
$$\int_0^x |f|^p = \int_0^1 \tfrac 12 |f|^p .$$
If we let $g_1 = f  1_{[0,x]}$ and $g_2 = f  1_{[x,1]}$ then
$\int_0^1 |g_i|^p= \tfrac 12 \int_0^1 |f|^p$. Since $|x^*(f)| \ge 1$ we must have that $|x^*(g_i)|\ge 1/2 $ for some $i=1,2$. Set $f_1 = 2g_i$ so that $|x^*(f_1)| \ge 1$ and $$\int_0^1 |f_1|^p=2^p \tfrac 12 \int_0^1 |f|^p= 2^{p-1}\int_0^1 |f|^p.$$
Arguing as above, replacing $f$ by $f_1$ you can find $f_2 \in L_p(0,1)$ such that $|x^*(f_2)| \ge 1$ and
$$ \int_0^1 |f_1|^p = 2^{p-1} \int_0^1 |f_1|^p = (2^{p-1})^2 \int_0^1 |f|^p. $$
Recursively define a sequence $(f_n)$ such that $|x^*(f_n)| \ge 1$ and $\int_0^1 |f_n|^p =(2^{p-1})^n \int_0^1 |f|^p \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ since $0<p<1$.

so can't get a example by hint above, right? and nice anwser.
